# strtok inserting junk into an array

Tags: c

I'm having some issues with `strtok`, Im basically reading a file line by line, separating the data I get from the file with `strtok` and then storing it into an array.

A row in my file looks like this (I have several lines, but the idea is the same).

file.txt

```
3 0 5 0 0 8 0 1 0
```

Im doing the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){

    FILE* file;
    char line[256];
    char* data[9];
    char* fileName = "file.txt";
    file = fopen(fileName, "r");

    fgets(line, sizeof(line), file);
    char* ptr = strtok(line," ");
    int i = 0;

    while(ptr != NULL && i<9){
        printf("%s",ptr);
        data[i] = ptr;
        i++;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    for(int z = 0; z<i; z++){
        printf( "%s", data[z]) ;
    };
    fclose(file);
}
```

Which gives me the output

```
3,0,5,0,0,8,0,1,0, (from the printf inside the while)
p��0�,�0�,�,,0,8,0,1,0 (from the data array)
```

Any idea on whats going on?

EDIT: Added spacing in txt file and separation between outputs. `i<9` was added in `while` statement (i<8 made it so the last digit was not being catched).

EDIT2: Problem was fixed by using `data[9]` instead of `data[8]`, being an array I thought the first element would be `data[0]` being `data[8]` the ninth.

Current output with code above:

```
3,0,5,0,0,8,0,1,0, (From ptr)
3,0,5,0,0,8,0,1,0, (From data array)
```

Comment: Please show a minimal `file.txt` instead of describing it. Side note: you need to check if `fopen` fails.

Comment: Please add some separator between the outputs, so it's easier to see each separate `strtok` call.

Comment: Also your second loop printing `data` is looping from index `0` to `9`. What if there isn't ten initialized elements in the `data` array? Especially considering that you define the `data` array to only have ***eight*** elements!!!

Comment: And please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). You need to show us the input that generates the output shown, as well as the expected output.

Comment: Change `for(int z = 0; z<9; z++)` for `for(int z = 0; z<i; z++)` and see what happens.

Comment: @MartinVéronneau Still UB if `i > 8`.

Comment: Ill update the question in a sec, regarding the last loop, as I am using "<", the 'data[9]' is not being reached.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Indeed, there's more problem looming in that code, but I'm trying to see if ruling out printing uninitialized char* causes the bad output.

Comment: @Manuel I do not see a blank in the data of the file.

Comment: Okay (regarding the condition of the last loop), but you still access the *ninth* element of an eight-element array. And since you don't have any bounds-checking in the `strtok` loop, you can easily go out of bounds of `data` there too.

Comment: since no blank in the lines, i=1 at the end, so first iteration should give a line itself and 7 remainings a garbage. possibly the garbage contains carriage return so the carriage goes to the beginning of line and overwrites the chars

Comment: @mangusta That's what I think too.

Comment: after the edits according the contents of file.xt: you have 9 tokens but `data` contains only 8 elements and 'i < 9' doeesn't prevent you from assigning sth. to `data[8]` which is already out of bounds and probably overwriting `line`

Comment: Don't change the code in the question according to answers! That makes answers (and possible comments) useless, and that makes the whole question useless. Remember that this site isn't only for you, it's for everyone who might have a similar problem to you. If an answer is "correct" you mark it as such (like you have) otherwise you add comments on the answers if they don't help, and upvote those who do help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are allocating way too small buffer for your line. Use `line[255]` or even bigger. Next you are trying to print null pointers from data array and `z<9` will lead to access out of bounds on index `8` as the last entry in data array is actually at index `7`. So the best solution will be to limit `for` loop by `i` which actually equals size of read data entries.

```
for(int z = 0; z<i; z++){
    printf( "%s", data[z]);
}
```

So you will be printing only non null entries from data array.

Last but not least as your data array can fit only 8 entries you need also change while loop to fit this limitation (or increase the size of the array):

```
while (ptr != NULL && i < 8) {
...
}
```

Comment: Edited the question with the recommendations, `i<8` made it so the last digit was not being catched, used `i<9` instead. Problem is that i'd still have a `z<9` in that case

Comment: Then increase data size to 9.